# Want to find intersecting angle (3D position) of two 3D points or Y distance

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have point A (x,y,z) and point B (x, y, z) in ARWorld. I want to keep point A horizontally parallel to B or let's say both should be on the surface.
See the image to get a better idea.

I am planning to get Y direction height or vertical height from A to B and then I will push down A by height. But how to find the height.

I want to keep A's x and z the same as it is.

Not sure how to articulate the issue, But aY - By does not work.
NOTE: A and B both are different Anchor in ARKit. Box/Mesh is on the anchor. Seems like I need global absolute world positions.
Is there any other way to get a rounded position in the image?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am a bit confused .... if you have only A and B then what exactly is the line vertical and horizontal line? .. Could you explain what exactly you mean by `I want to keep point A horizontally parallel` ... you mean you simply want that their global `Y` is equal? So simply `pointA.y = pointB.y`?

Comment: The line is for understanding, I want to make A parallel to B (Horizontally). So in the image, I want the circle's position to shift A from its position.

Comment: So if you mean the global Y axis then wouldn't `pointA.y = pointB.y;` already do this? and the distance (if you need it at all) would simply be `pointB.y - pointA.y`

Comment: I want to maintain X and Z position the same as it was. If I change Y only then I get a new position somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry X and Z Edited.

Comment: Why would `X` and `Z` change if you only do `pointA.y = pointB.y;` ? Be aware that I am talking about absolute world space positions ... the values will ofcourse be different in the Inspector since there you see only the local positions relative to the parent

Comment: New A.y pushed distance = A.y - b.y. Ie A.y = 10, B.y=3 . Push 10-3=7 down.

Comment: @joreldraw close but no ;) The distance to move A is `b.y - a.y` e.g. `b.y = 3` and `a.y=10` => move `a.y` about `3 - 10 = -7` ;) so 7 downwards ... but as said you can as well just directly assign them `a.y = b.y` .. no need to calculate the distance at all

Comment: Both are different anchors (A and B). So both are not horizontal planes. Only B is plane and A is Anchor - ARKIT

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to get the `positionA` mapped down to the same "height" (Y axis) level as `positionB`

```
positionA.y = positionB.y;
```

it is simple as that.

Be aware that I am talking about absolute **world space positions** ... the values will of course be different in the Inspector since there you see only the **local positions** relative to the parent.

So when we are talking about `GameObject`s what you want to do is

```
var positionA = objectA.transform.position;
var positionB = objectB.transform.position;

positionA.y = positionB.y;

objectA.transform.position = positionA;
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/K59PDQB  It does not give what i want,

Comment: The easy way would be find the distance bw two object and then move it.

Comment: @indrajit well are you sure that the yellow plate is not just appearing to be higher due to perspective? It is also pretty hard for us to figure out what exactly you are doing .. could you show the code you are using?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Blue is my horizontal plane detected by ARKit. Yellow is mine.

Comment: @indrajit yes but it might just be "behind" the AR plane ... not really above it. It might just appear that way because of the perspective .. as said it is pretty hard to tell what doesn't work in your specific case ... are you sure the plane of ARKit is Unity world aligned  XZ parallel? Or is it possible it brings on own rotation?

Comment: I am not sure as I am new to ARKit. So do you think A = (0.44,0.33,-1.44) and B = (.23,0.42,-1.57) putting 0.33 instead 0.42 will make both paralleled. Both Mesh/Box are not in one anchor, Both are separate anchor in ARKIT.

Comment: As said you don't want to look at the values in the Inspector at all .. these are the local positions ... what you want to set is the global absolute world positions and then you would want to have `0.42` for the A if you want to bring A to the level of B .. not the other way round ;

Answer (score 0):

I would make an horizontal plane in `B` find the closest point in that plane to `A` and move `A` to that point.

Create horizontal [plane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html):
Taking the constructor into account `Plane(Vector3 inNormal, Vector3 inPoint);`.

```
Plane myPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, <Bpositon>)
```

Then with `Plane.ClosestPointOnPlane` you can find the closest point to A in your horizontal plane.

```
Vector3 closestPoint = myPlane.ClosestPointOnPlane(<APosition>);
```

Then you can move `A` to that point.

```
APosition = closesPoint;
```

Conviniently the closest point in the plane to one point is the one perpendicular to the plane, so the one "horizontally parallel" I believe you are after.

Comment: I am using Swift - ARKit. Is there any way to get calculation or formula ?

Comment: why the unity3d tag in the question then?

Comment: So I can get a formula or calculation. I get too little attention without unity3d

Comment: tags are not to draw attention, are to define the problem. When tags are misused, this leads to the waste of time and effort of the people that gladly like to help. You need to set the tags that correctly apply to your problem in the proper stack exchange site, and if your question does not draw the desired attention you can set a bounty.

Comment: Matrix and AR are not bounded to ARKit-Swift only. The formula can be generated in any language. Yet, I will take care of it. Thanks

Comment: @rustyBucketBay how would this be any different from just doing `positionA.y = positionB.y;` ? ^^ If you anyway use the `Vector3.Up` for your plane using `ClosestPointOnPlane` is completely redundant

Comment: true, good point. Guess I overthought the problem. In case the problem was not in the world's horizontal plane (XZ), guess this approach could be useful just fitting the A-B vector in the plane's normal argument in the plane construction

Comment: or for the case of need of paralelism to any plane of choice (defined at the plane construction), one of whom could be the horizontal one...

Comment: https://ibb.co/K59PDQB This is the problem. I want yellow grounded same as blue,

Comment: aY - bY does not work. I do not know how to articulate the issue.

Comment: yea, should not directly work unless you apply all the plane stuff shown in the answer. You can check Mr @derHugo answer which is simpler and more direct if you are working in the horizontal plane, which seem to be the case. Just making the A point y coordinate equal to B's y coordinate, lowers down A point to B's horizontal

Comment: Both are different anchors (A and B). So both are not horizontal planes. Only B is plane and A is Anchor - ARKIT